# Need help understanding this option quote

Tags: options

Can you please help me understand what is happening here. This is my first options trade. The stock is currently selling at $1510.

I bought a 1480/1500 spread with Jan 15 exp. Yet it shows a loss everyday.[image: the trade]

Comment: The price quote of 45.00 for the 1480 call is clearly wrong.  The last trade for the 1480 call in Toronto is recorded at 96.90.  The last trade for the 1500 is 86.65.  See [TMX Money](https://money.tmx.com/en/quote/SHOP/options).

Comment: One of the two options quotes is definitely bad or stale data.  Check the prices during real time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we've been getting a lot of "mysterious" options questions lately that can all be explained by stale quotes

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD - "Mysterious" options questions?  LOL.  If this is a duplicate question then you should find an original and link it here so that the OP gets an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3):

After hours, options are not traded, and most professional traders remove their bids/asks from the order book (or use 'valid for day' so they auto-expire).
As a consequence, checking values after hours leads typically to absurd high or low values (based on 'mark', which is the midpoint between whatever remaining bids/asks are around). You are basically looking at trash numbers.

Do not take any valuation serious that doesn't happen during option trading hours, and even then, make sure the 'value' is not from the last trade from days or more ago.

Just a well-meant hint: You might want to refrain from options trading while you struggle with such elementary things; or you might end up paying dearly for the lessons.

Comment: Just regarding the excellent final paragraph. Nowadays when folks say to me I WANT TO !!!TRADE!!!  I tell them to go ahead, take 10 or 20 grand, and trade ("!!!!") as hard and fast as possible. In this way the money will be gone as soon as possible (obviously, it's all going anyway). So no time is wasted. They will have a fantastic lesson as soon as possible.  Folks commonly spend 10s of thousands on things like college, so, might as well just go for it.